# changing text direction (rtl to ltr) of a single post title in WP

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a website in an RTL language and I want to add a single post with an english (...LTR) title. For some reason the only class that is unique to the specific post is a long string of letters, numbers and symbols and the built in css editor doesn't react too well to it... The post I'm talking about is "We like facebook!" and as you can see here:

[image]

The exclamation mark shows at the beginning of the word. Any help would be great!
thank you

Comment: `.yourRealCrazyClassName > .layer-content { text-direction: ltr; color: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

If this is just an aesthetic issue on site, you can try this:

```
.your-parent-class-name .layer-content:before {
    content: "!";
}
```

It might be :after rather than :before but I think the r-to-l text might mean you should use before to put the exclamation mark at the end.

Obviously you'd delete the exclamation from the post title and don't expect it to appear on shares, newsletter feeds, etc.